# JS Doc is displaying description wierdly

Tags: jsdoc

## Problem

I am busy writing out a tutorial for myself about jenkins and I am using jsdoc to do it.
anyways I noticed on the homepage that the section that reads the Readme.md is displaying very strangely.

[image]

jsdoc.json

```json
{
  "source": {
      "include": ["src"],
      "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
      "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs)_"
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "tags": {
      "allowUnknownTags": true,
      "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
  },
  "templates": {
      "cleverLinks": true,
      "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts":{
      "recurse": true,
      "destination": "./docs/",
      "tutorials": "./tutorials",
      "readme": "README.md"
  }
}
```

README.md

```
# LearningJenkins

## Tutorials
<!-- [Link to tutorials](https://codenameninja.github.io/LearningJenkins/) -->
```

Comment: Have you checked the encoding on the file? I just had a brief look and github is saying it's a binary file

Comment: where would I check the encoding of the file?

Comment: If you're using VS Code, you can open the file and look in the bottom right where it will say `ANSI`, or `UTF-xxx`, that's the encoding. I grabbed the file and it says it's `UTF-16 LE` (check to confirm). JSDoc doesn't work with UTF-16 (every character is 2 bytes instead of 1) so you'll need to save that file as UTF-8 encoding (also via VS code if you click on the encoding)